# IOS developer program( individual)

Tags: iphone

My clients has purchased an IOS developer program (individual company), he would like to put to the apple store with the name of his company ? can he do this ? How ? or the app will have the name of his program developer ?

Comment: Voted to close. You need to ask this on the apple developer forums.

Comment: This is off topic. On [the App Stores proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores), though, this would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specified in iTunes connect, when he publishes an app to the Apple App Store.

The app will have the legal name of the name on the account.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of the question, but if the company is registered to the program, he can give the developer access under his account.
If you're asking about him being registered as a person, it can only be posted under the person's name.